# In Vim, is it possible to add and subtract highlighting attributes instead of override them?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to do something like the following, which doesn't work?

```
" Add bold styling while preserving underlining
highlight Underlined gui+=bold
```

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work then it is not possible to do it. You will have to parse the output of `execute('hi Underlined')` and build the right command manually.